# Should we make the EPUB3 a community wiki question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

The question [Which ereaders support the EPUB3 format?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/114/which-ereaders-support-the-epub3-format) is list question where the answer will vary overtime.  Should it be converted to a community wiki question?

@eyal (OP) has argued in the comments that he supports this action.

Answer (score 4):

My argument is simple; the subject matter for this site is relatively narrow. Having some canonical, updatable answers available will make it a useful resource for the larger audience of ereader users.

I asked this question because I saw it as a useful followup for someone reading the answer to [what is the difference between epub2 and epub3](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-are-the-differences-between-epub2-and-epub3). It was the first thing I wondered after reading that question, and I think the answer to it should be here as well.

I think this usefulness overrides the drawback - that such a question is not ideally suited for Stack Exchange sites because it needs to be updated.

Comment: Yup. It's the sort of question that is worth establishing as a reference, and it can be updated as time goes on. There's precedent for establishing canonical questions/answers across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense…

Meaning: I would surely agree that it would be fit as a wiki-question. We will have to expect frequent updates, but it would definitely represent a valuable resource to the ebook community, both from a reader's as well as from a publisher's point of view.